# Bootstrap glyphicon not changing color on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I apply

```
.chats a:hover {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
}
```

to:

```
<a href=''>
    <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'</span></div>
    <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Sergey Brin</strong></div>
    <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
    <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Come down to the Googleplex for an interview. We would like to talk to you about some exciti...</p>
</a>
```

Only the class `.sender` gets a color of white. All other things, glyphicon, `<p>`, and `.timestamp` are unchanged on hover. Why is this?

```css
.glyphicon-user {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #3399ff;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.panel-heading h1 {
 padding-bottom: 0.65em;
 color: #3399ff;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-body {
 padding: 0;
}

.col-xs-12 {
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.chats {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.chats li {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

.chats a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 85px;
 padding: 15px 0;
}

.chats a:hover {
 background-color: #3399ff;
 color: white;
}

.chats .sender {
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.chats .timestamp {
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.chats .chat-sample {
 clear: right;
 margin-left: 50px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.chats:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-centered'>
    <div class='panel panel-default'>
     <div class='panel-heading'>
      <div class='btn-group pull-left'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'</span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
         <li><a href='#'>Delete All Chats</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
       <div class='dropdown'>
        <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
        </button>
        <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
         <li><a href='#'>New Chat</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
      <h1 class='panel-title text-center'>FunChat</h1>
     </div>
     <div class='panel-body'>
      <ul class='chats'>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'</span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>What time is it?</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'</span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Verizon Wireless</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Your bill is due on 12/12/2012. Please pay before the due date to avoid service interuption. ...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href=''>
         <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'</span></div>
         <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Sergey Brin</strong></div>
         <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
         <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Come down to the Googleplex for an interview. We would like to talk to you about some exciti...</p>
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div><!--end column-->
  </div><!--end row 1-->
 </div><!--end container-->
```

Comment: You are missing a close `>` at the end of the first `<span>` tag. `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'</span>` should be `<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span>`

Comment: @JamesDouglas fixed. Still same behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Try this now

```
a:hover > .glyphicon{
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Why try this? What does it do? What did you change? How does it solve the problem? (Provide some explanation).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
.chats a:hover > *, .chats a:hover .glyphicon {
  background-color: #3399ff;
  color: white;
}
```

The Bootstrap seems to be giving some styles to the `.text-muted` and various other elements and takes priority over the `:hover` because it is more exact. The above code will override the Bootstrap styles instead. (Only on hover though)

```css
.glyphicon-user {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #3399ff;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.panel-heading h1 {
  padding-bottom: 0.65em;
  color: #3399ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}

.col-xs-12 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.chats {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chats li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

.chats a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 85px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.chats a:hover {
 background-color: #3399ff;
 color: white;
}
.chats a:hover > *, .chats a:hover .glyphicon {
  background-color: #3399ff;
  color: white;
}

.chats .sender {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.chats .timestamp {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.chats .chat-sample {
  clear: right;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.chats:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-centered'>
      <div class='panel panel-default'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
          <div class='btn-group pull-left'>
            <div class='dropdown'>
              <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span>
        </button>
              <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                <li><a href='#'>Delete All Chats</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Log Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='btn-group pull-right'>
            <div class='dropdown'>
              <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' type='button'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
        </button>
              <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
                <li><a href='#'>New Chat</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h1 class='panel-title text-center'>FunChat</h1>
        </div>
        <div class='panel-body'>
          <ul class='chats'>
            <li>
              <a href=''>
                <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
                <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>John Appleseed</strong></div>
                <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
                <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>What time is it?</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=''>
                <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
                <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Verizon Wireless</strong></div>
                <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
                <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Your bill is due on 12/12/2012. Please pay before the due date to avoid service interuption. ...</p>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href=''>
                <div class='chat-img pull-left'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></div>
                <div class='sender pull-left'><strong>Sergey Brin</strong></div>
                <div class='timestamp text-muted pull-right'><small><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Thursday</small></div>
                <p class='chat-sample text-muted'>Come down to the Googleplex for an interview. We would like to talk to you about some exciti...</p>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end column-->
  </div>
  <!--end row 1-->
</div>
<!--end container-->
```

Comment: @RobertRocha How's my answer?

Comment: Why try this? What does it do? What did you change? How does it solve the problem? (Provide some explanation).

Comment: @JamesDouglas not bad. For some reason the background color of your solution adds some outside padding

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to use same style for all icons:

```
.chats a:hover span.glyphicon {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
}
```

and this if you want different styles for individual icon:

```
.chats a:hover span.your_glyphicon_name {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the CSS

```
.chats a:hover > *,
.chats a:hover .glyphicon {
    background-color: #3399ff;
    color: white;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27fqkt1L/)

Comment: Hi James. There was no answer when I started mine, and both our answers are not the same so I dont know why you are calling me out here?

Comment: Ok sorry, I know what you mean. This actually works better than my original, but I've edited since then.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes multiple working answers are posted without malicious intend at the same time. It happens.